# AGGrid - RowGroupOpened - How to distinguish between opening and closing a group? (Server side model)

Tags: angular, ag-grid

According to the AG Grid docs, the RowGroupOpened is fired when a Row Group is opened as well as when a Row Group is closed. I am using Angular 7 and AG Grid Enterprise Version 20 (evaluation phase).

I need to distinguish these two events in order to keep an expandedGroupIds Array up-to-date. The array should only contain the groups that are currently opened.

I am using this array for restoring the previous group state after server side sorting has been performed (according to this documentation: https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-server-side-model-grouping/#preserving-group-state)

This is my event handler code. The problem is that the event is also fired after the user clicked on a column for sorting. In that case, the elements are removed unintendedly from the array and the next sorting leads to all row groups being closed.

```
onRowGroupOpened(event) {
if(event.data.id) {
  if (this.gridDataSource.hasExpandedGroupId(event.data.id)) {
    this.gridDataSource.removeExpandedGroupId(event.data.id);
  } else {
    this.gridDataSource.addExpandedGroupId(event.data.id);
  }
}}
```

Thank you for your help.
Kind regards
Patrick

Answer (score 3):

I have not used server side model, but don't think the implementation will vary. You can make use of the `expanded` property to distinguish opening or closing event of a group. Here is an example -

```
onRowGroupOpened(params) {
if(params.node.expanded) {
   // node was expanded, do your logic
   this.gridDataSource.addExpandedGroupId(params.data.id);
} else {
  // node was collapsed, so remove if present
     if (this.gridDataSource.hasExpandedGroupId(params.data.id)) {
       this.gridDataSource.removeExpandedGroupId(params.data.id);
      }
 }
}
```

This way, you can maintain list of expanded node Ids